# Changing CSS elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using javascript, I'm trying to change the background image of a div class when particular url params are entered. However it isn't switching the image in the background.

Example url:

```
 example.com?campaignid=street
```

The HTML

```
<div class="row-background-79134">
    <p>Some content here</p>
</div>
```

The script is here:

```
<script>
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');
    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }
    return params;
}

var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
var myCampaign = query.campaignid;


if (myCampaign == "street"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
}

if (myCampaign == "plumber"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image2.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
}

if (myCampaign == "cowboy"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image3.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
}

if (myCampaign == "hairdresser"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image4.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
}

</script>
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Try using `backgroundImage` instead, and assign the `no-repeat center center` in the CSS file instead (since it never changes, there is no reason assigning this in js).

Comment: Please rename your images with the possible values of myCampaign or create a dictionary for correspondences in order to suppress all conditions. That allow to avoid code repetition.

Answer (score 2):

Each of these blocks

```
if (myCampaign == "street"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
}
```

Should be re-written with an extra brace, like this

```
if (myCampaign == "street"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
       elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center;';
   } // added this
}
```

Also consider adding some logging. Use `console.log` to show you what's going on, and open your browser console to read the output. You probably want to know what the value of `myCampaign` is, for instance.

```
console.log(myCampaign);
```

will help, near the top. There are other ways to make the code a bit easier to read/maintain, but getting the braces right should be the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Your code `if` statements are missing a closing bracket `}`. However, the major problem here is that your code is much larger than it should be, and is a redundant mess.

To fix this, it is a much better idea to store the campaign names and image values in a object, then have *one* `if` statement:

```js
//This would be the value you get from the URL, I've replaced it with a prompt for demo purposes
var campaignName = prompt("campaign name? (leave blank for default)") || "street";

//Object containing a name/image pair for each of the campaigns
var campaigns = {
  street: "image1.jpg",
  plumber: "image2.jpg",
  cowboy: "image3.jpg",
  hairdresser: "image4.jpg"
};

//If a campaign with the name exists
if (campaigns[campaignName]) {
  
  //Select elements by class name
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
  
  //Loop through elements
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    
    //Since we have the other styles added with CSS, we only have to set the background-image
    elems[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://example.com/' + campaigns[campaignName] + ')';
    
    //Logging for demo purposes
    console.log("Added image to", elems[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.row-background-79134 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row-background-79134"></div>
<div class="row-background-79134"></div>
<div class="row-background-79134"></div>
<div class="row-background-79134"></div>
```

Much cleaner, simpler, and easier to debug.

If you want to add a new campaign/image, just add it to the campaigns object:

```
var campaigns = {
  street: "image1.jpg",
  plumber: "image2.jpg",
  cowboy: "image3.jpg",
  hairdresser: "image4.jpg",
  chef: "image5.jpg",
};
```

Comment: Thanks for removing unnecessary conditions

Answer (score 0):

Try this, There are syntax issues in your code. You did not close your brackets properly.

```
if (myCampaign == "street"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
   elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image1.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
   }
}

if (myCampaign == "plumber"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image2.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
    }
}

if (myCampaign == "cowboy"){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image3.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
  }
}

if (myCampaign == "hairdresser"){
   var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
   for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image4.jpg) no-repeat center center;'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each if bracket, youre missing a "}" which should close this block. In addition to that, next to the background assignment you are missing a ";",

wrong:

```
if (myCampaign == "cowboy"){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image3.jpg no-repeat center center;'
  }
```

right:

```
if (myCampaign == "cowboy"){
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
  for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
     elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image3.jpg no-repeat center center;';
  }
}
```

If you want to make your current code shorter, use jQuery.

JavaScript:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('row-background-79134');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
 elems[i].style.background = 'url(https://example.com/image4.jpg) no-repeat center center;';
}
```

jQuery

```
$(".row-background-79134").css("background","url('https://example.com/image4.jpg') no-repeat center center");
```